# Finding map icons for famous Paris landmarks?

Tags: openstreetmap, point-of-interest, france

Where can I find map icons for famous Paris landmarks?

I am looking for icons for famous landmarks in Paris, such as the Eiffel Tower, Arc de Triomphe, Louvre, Notre Dame. These should do. For other poi's I have general category-icons, but it would be nice to have special onces for the most well-known. (also from a ux-standpoint: i.e: 'getting your bearings' it would be great)

Anyone knows where to look?

Comment: what size do you want the icons to be?

Comment: 48x48px max, approx correctly aligned to the map perspective (mapbox style) and all icons in the same style for bonus! :)

Answer (score 2):

Do a Google image search on "free landmark icon". There are tons but whether you'll find all the ones you're after I don't know. [Vector Stock](http://www.vectorstock.com/) seem to do a range but I can't say I've ever used them.

Failing that, download [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) and make your own!